# Python regex to catch Verilog port names

Tags: python, python-3.x, verilog

I have some output port statements in verilog text file as shown below and I want to capture Just port names.

Example sample:

```
output Y;
output Y1,Y2,Y3;
output Z;
output Q, QN;
```

Expected output I want is a list with output port names

```
(Y)
(Y1, Y2, Y3)
(Z)
(Q,QN)
```

I tried below code but it doesn't give me the list quite I want.

```
outputPortListPattern=re.compile(r'^\s*(output)\s+(.*);',flags=re.M)
with open(fileA) as fh_in:
    with open(fileB, "w") as fh_out:
        for line in fh_in:
            match=outputPortListPattern.match(line)
            if match:
                matchlist = match.group(2)
                print("Output port list={}".format(matchlist))
```

Comment: If you need this to _not_ randomly break in interesting ways at inopportune times I'd recommend you to just pick an off-the-shelf verilog parser (like this: https://pypi.org/project/pyverilog/) and use the methods from that to get at the ports.

Comment: There are many different ways to declare ports in verilog. Your example shows a very specific one. Is it what you want? What about other or missing directions, types embedded in the line, ansi headers, ...?

Comment: Yes, I have a single ".v" file with thousands modules with exact same output port declaration format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `list` of port names you want, then:

```
import re

text = """output Y;
output Y1,Y2,Y3;
output Z;
output Q, QN;"""

[re.split(r',\s*', m.group(1))
    for m in re.finditer(r'^output\s+(([^,;]+)(\s*,([^,;]+))*);$', text, flags=re.M)
]
```

Prints:

```
[['Y'], ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], ['Z'], ['Q', 'QN']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have the format `output PORT1, PORT2, ..., PORTN;`. You can use the following code that doesn't need a regex:

```
for line in fh_in:
    ports = line.replace('output ', '')[:-1]
    print(f'({ports})')
```

Obviously, you will need to open the files using `with`.

If your input file is:

```
output Y;
output Y1,Y2,Y3;
output Z;
output Q, QN;
```

Your output will be:

```
(Y)
(Y1,Y2,Y3)
(Z)
(Q, QN)
```